# Register Externally hosted app in PCF Service Registry

Tags: asp.net-4.0, netflix-eureka, cloud-foundry, steeltoe

I am trying to add an ASP.NET 4.x app hosted externally (using AWS Elastic Beanstalk) into the Service-registry of an existing PCF. 
Edit: Is this possible? If so, can someone give me an example about how this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by Daniel Mikusa is very appropriate for how I achieved this.

> For Pivotal SCS, you would want to create a service instance (if you
>   don't have one already), then create a service key for your external
>   app. That will give you all of the binding info/creds you need to
>   connect from your remote service. A service key is the same as binding
>   a service to an app, except it's not tied to an app so it works well
>   for situations like this. Just give your service key a good name, so
>   you know that it's being used by an external app when you come back
>   and see it a year from now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have network connectivity in all directions between apps in PCF and the external app, yes this should be quite possible.

However, if you're using Spring Cloud Eureka, your externally-hosted app will need to get valid OAuth credentials so that it can authenticate prior to registering.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Can you please give me an example of how I can achieve this

Comment: I don't love this solution, but you can deploy an app (any HelloWorld app would work) to PCF, bind it to the Eureka instance you wish to register with, then take the vcap:services entries and plug them in to the AWS-hosted app. You would probably need to leave that app deployed for the credentials to remain valid, but I've not tested this scenario.

Comment: We have several ASP.NET 4x samples for service discovery available here: https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/2.x/Discovery/src but no examples of the hosting scenario you're asking about

Comment: For Pivotal SCS, you would want to create a service instance (if you don't have one already), then create a service key for your external app. That will give you all of the binding info/creds you need to connect from your remote service. A service key is the same as binding a service to an app, except it's not tied to an app so it works well for situations like this. Just give your service key a good name, so you know that it's being used by an external app when you come back and see it a year from now.